# How to call ipdb when a test fails in django testing?

Tags: django, django-testing

I would like to start ipdb every time a test fails.
I tried

```
$ ipython manage.py test myapp --pdb
```

but doesn't works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you `pip install ipdbplugin` and `pip install django-nose`, then  add `django_nose` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` and set `TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'`, you can then call:

```
./manage.py test --ipdb
```

or

```
./manage.py test --ipdb-failures
```

See https://github.com/flavioamieiro/nose-ipdb and https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose for further details.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to install the [`nose`](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/) 
and [`django-nose`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-nose) packages. After you configure `django-nose` for your project, the default test runner and `test` management command will be beefed up with the `nose` test runner supports.

Here's [a gist with the output](https://gist.github.com/2597247) of the `python manage.py help test` command that shows the impressive list of options you get for running tests after the setup.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [django-pdb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pdb) app. Only install in your settings project

Comment: It seems to be exactly what I wanted, but I guess it is conflicting with django-userena.
when django-pdg installed, I see this:
`relation "userena_userenasignup" does not exist`